# Kotlin Android Studio - Find Array

Tags: kotlin-android-extensions

Good morning people.
I'm developing an app in Android Studio. I have a doubt. I have an EditText that the user enters a code, and next to it I have a button. When the user enters the value and presses the button, I want the system to look for the descriptions of that code. For example, suppose that code 10 has a list of descriptions, such as expiry, weight, etc.. and code 20 also has a list of descriptions, such as expiry, weight, etc... but when the user enters the code, the system would fetch those values ​​and insert those values ​​into a TextView. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

> you have to input the data into the database and use keywords to call the contents of each you input

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).